# ¿Se puede aceptar una respuesta y otorgar una recompensa a otra respuesta?

Tags: soporte, recompensas

Tengo una duda con [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29854/c%C3%B3mo-descargar-al-tablet-una-app-con-c%C3%B3digo-de-descarga-gratis-sin-pasar-por-e/30228?noredirect=1#comment51793_30228) que hice a la que asigné una recompensa de +50.

Tengo dos respuestas, pero ninguna de ellas me responde para hacer lo que yo quería hacer. Di la recompensa a la única respuesta que intenta darme alternativas a lo que yo quería hacer. Y luego tengo una respuesta basada en el criterio oficial de lo que se debe hacer. Pero que no me sirve.

¿Puedo dar los +50 al que intenta darme un respuesta basada en lo que yo pregunto y aceptar la respuesta que dice lo que hay que hacer oficialmente, aunque esta no me resuelva mi problema?

O es mejor que espere recibir la respuesta buena, si existe que creo que no existe. ¿Qué debo hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí. Se puede otorgar una recompensa a una respuesta *A* y aceptar una respuesta *B* (en cualquier orden cronológico, como quieras). Las recompensas y la aceptación de una respuesta son totalmente independientes<sup>**1**</sup> una de otra.

Uno esperaría que, siendo el autor de la pregunta, aceptes y recompenses a la misma respuesta. Eso sería lo lógico para la mayoría de los casos. Pero hay muchas excepciones válidas. En todo caso, un simple comentario puede ayudar a explicar tus acciones.

En tu caso particular, otorgaría la recompensa a la mejor respuesta hasta ahora (aunque también podrías dejar sin otorgar y que se encargue el sistema), y dejaría la pregunta sin aceptar ninguna respuesta, mostrando que aún no fue solucionada.

Lo importante es tener un criterio coherente: hacer una pregunta que pueda tener una única respuesta y ser claro en el motivo de la recompensa. Es decir, los casos donde se acepta una respuesta y se recompensa a otra porque responde a otra parte de la pregunta se deberían evitar.

---

**1:** Con una excepción. Si aceptaste una respuesta y termina la recompensa y su período de gracia sin que otorgues la recompensa, el sistema otorgará automáticamente la mitad de la recompensa a la respuesta aceptada.

Comment: Gracias @Mariano está clarísimo!

Answer (score 1):

Si ninguna respuesta responde realmente tu pregunta, lo mejor es **no aceptar ninguna**. Recuerda que la respuesta aceptada es lo que debería ayudar a la comunidad y a futuros visitantes a tu pregunta a comprender que en situaciones similares deberían seguir lo que indica la respuesta aceptada (porque tú seguiste ese consejo y funcionó para ti). Si sientes que dicha respuesta te ayudó en tu solución, puedes darle un punto a favor.

Sobre la recompensa, si no hay una respuesta aceptada y tampoco has escogido una respuesta que deba merecerla por completo, entonces el sistema automáticamente brindará la mitad de la recompensa a la respuesta con más votos. Recuerda que una vez que pusiste la recompensa, esos 50 puntos se descontaron de tu reputación y están como "en el aire", es decir que no los puedes recuperar.

Comment: Respondiendo a la 1ª parte de tu respuesta: Ninguna de las dos respuestas que tengo responde a lo que yo necesito y no he seguido ninguno de los consejos que me proponen. Respondiendo a la 2ª parte de tu respuesta: Lo de los +50 y que se reparte ya lo se. La pregunta era si se podía dar +50 a una respuesta y el visto bueno a otra que no sea aquella a la que di +50.

Comment: @MarcLemien si tú has creado la pregunta y puesto la recompensa, no puedes.

Comment: Yo he creado la pregunta @LuiggiMendoza y también he puesto la recompensa a aquel que más se esforzó en buscar una opción a lo que yo quería. Pero como no me sirve ni una ni la otra no he puesto el visto bueno. - ¿Si aparece alguien dándome una respuesta buena, le podré dar a él el visto bueno?, ¿O estoy obligado a dar el visto bueno a quien di el +50?

Comment: Si no entregas la recompensa el sistema lo hará a la respuesta con mayor puntaje, y solo otorgará la mitad del puntaje. La otra mitad desaparecerá. Y sí, siempre puedes marcar una respuesta como aceptada cuando tú lo decidas, incluso puedes cambiar tu decision sobre cuál es la respuesta aceptada. Aceptar una respuesta no es definitivo, no cierras la pregunta. Inclusive si hay una respuesta aceptada, se pueden seguir publicando respuestas a tu pregunta.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Probablemente haya un malentendido en la pregunta y comentario, pero quiero aclarar algo, según lo que entendí yo [que preguntaba](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/2505): **Sí**, se puede otorgar una recompensa a una respuesta _A_ y aceptar una respuesta _B_ (en cualquier orden cronológico). Más info: [_Is it OK to accept one answer and award bounty to another?_](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319208/5290909). Lo único que se ve afectado por una aceptación es el otorgamiento automático por el sistema de una recompensa no otorgada por el usuario.

Comment: Esto claramente debería ser más la excepción que la regla. Se esperaría que en la mayoría de los casos se acepte y se le dé la recompensa a la misma respuesta. Sin embargo, se puede, y las excepciones existen y están bien justificadas

Comment: Gracias @Mariano no se porque pero por más que he intentado explicarme bien Luiggi nunca ha entendido lo que preguntaba. Asi que lo que dices si lo publicas como respuesta daré el visto bueno, porque de momento no puedo.

Comment: @Marc Nos pasa a todos, y me pasó mil veces: creemos que alguien está preguntando algo diferente y seguimos contestando a lo que habíamos interpretado.. Esperemos a que Luiggi lo lea fuera del horario laboral y ahí vemos si edita o no... La respuesta de él sigue teniendo casi todo lo que hay que responder en este caso, y mejor tener respuestas de un moderador para estos casos.

Comment: bueno pues me espero.